# Debian 11 issue with locale: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, locale

The problem I encounter with Debian bullseye (v11):

If I execute `locale -a`, I get the following output:

```bsh
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
aa_DJ
aa_DJ.iso88591
aa_DJ.utf8
aa_ER
aa_ER.utf8
...
zh_TW
zh_TW.big5
zh_TW.euctw
zh_TW.utf8
zu_ZA
zu_ZA.iso88591
zu_ZA.utf8
```

Also, if I try to use `tlmgr` (package manager for LateX), I get the following:

```bsh
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:fr:en_GB",
        LC_ALL = "en-US.UTF-8",
        LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("fr_FR.UTF-8").
tlmgr: no action given; try --help if you need it.
```

I searched the issue, and tried the following:

- `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selecting only used locales (fr utf8, en-us utf8 and en-gb utf8)
- `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selecting all locales (as you can see above)
- `locale-gen`
- restarting the PC with each change
- editing /etc/default/locale

## More information

`cat /etc/default/locale` gives:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
```

`ls /usr/share/locale/en` gives:

```bsh
LC_MESSAGES
```

`ls /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES` gives:

```bsh
accounts-service.mo  gtk30-properties.mo  iso_3166-2.mo  kcoreaddons5_qt.qm  kwidgetsaddons5_qt.qm
cups-pk-helper.mo    gtk30.mo
```

## Questions

- Should I reconfigure locales and only select used locales?
- The error message says that it expects file/folder that does not exist. Where should this file/folder be located? in `/usr/share/locale/en`?
- How to solve this issue (non-blocking, because all applications seem to work, but annoying)?

If you have suggestions for documentations to read to dive deeper on this issue I'm also all hear.

Thank you.

## Edits

### Questions from @StéphaneChazelas

Output of `locale`

```bsh
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:fr:en_GB
LC_CTYPE="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en-US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en-US.UTF-8
```

Output of `strace locale 2>&1 | grep ENOENT`:

```bsh
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en-US/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

`ls /usr/lib/locale` gives:

```bsh
C.UTF-8
locale-archive
```

### Strange dpkg-reconfigure locales output

If I'm not wrong, `dpkg-reconfigure locales` should list locales and say for each of them "up to date" if already generated. But in my case, it re-process each locale and says "done":

```bsh
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
  LANGUAGE = "en_US:fr:en_GB",
  LC_ALL = "en-US.UTF-8",
  LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8",
  LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
  LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8",
  LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("fr_FR.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  aa_DJ.UTF-8... done
  aa_DJ.ISO-8859-1... done
  aa_ER.UTF-8... done
  aa_ER.UTF-8@saaho... done
  aa_ET.UTF-8... done
  af_ZA.UTF-8... done
  af_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
  agr_PE.UTF-8... done
  ak_GH.UTF-8... done
  am_ET.UTF-8... done
  an_ES.UTF-8... done
  an_ES.ISO-8859-15... done
  anp_IN.UTF-8... done
  ar_AE.UTF-8... done
  ar_AE.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_BH.UTF-8... done
  ar_BH.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_DZ.UTF-8... done
  ar_DZ.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_EG.UTF-8... done
  ar_EG.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_IN.UTF-8... done
  ar_IQ.UTF-8... done
  ...
```

### Question by @K-att-

`dpkg -l | grep "language-pack"` does not return anything.

### Question from @ThatsWhatSheCoded

`sudo apt-get install -y locales locales-all`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
locales is already the newest version (2.31-13+deb11u2).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  locales-all
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 227 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 locales-all amd64 2.31-13+deb11u2 [10.8 MB]
Fetched 10.8 MB in 21s (515 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
apt-listchanges: Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_GB:en_US:fr",
        LC_ALL = "en-US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MESSAGES = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("fr_FR.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package locales-all.
(Reading database ... 182206 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales-all_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking locales-all (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
Setting up locales-all (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
```

After restarting, `locale -a` still gives:

```bsh
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
...
```

### Print of `env` after reinstalling `locales`

Executed: `sudo apt-get remove locale`, then `sudo apt-get install -y locales` and then `env`:

```bsh
SHELL=/bin/bash
WINDOWID=79691783
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
KDED_STARTED_BY_KDEINIT=1
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:fr
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-eAB2uCmvHnDY/agent.872
SHELL_SESSION_ID=08a2a2b1e969432881e34e2775568d69
DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
SSH_AGENT_PID=911
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/nkoniishvt/.gtkrc:/home/nkoniishvt/.config/gtkrc
XCURSOR_SIZE=24
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
XDG_SEAT=seat0
PWD=/home/nkoniishvt
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
LOGNAME=nkoniishvt
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
XAUTHORITY=/home/nkoniishvt/.Xauthority
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/nkoniishvt/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/nkoniishvt/.config/gtkrc-2.0
HOME=/home/nkoniishvt
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.63
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/1
PROFILEHOME=
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
KONSOLE_VERSION=201203
KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=nkoniishvt
COLORFGBG=15;0
KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_VTNR=7
XDG_SESSION_ID=3
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_ALL=en-US.UTF-8
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors
KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
PATH=/home/nkoniishvt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE=1
KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW=/Windows/1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: What's the output of `locale` and of `strace locale 2>&1 | grep ENOENT`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I did not have strace installed and the strace + grep returned blank. I edited the output after installing strace

Comment: dpkg -l |grep "language-pack-en" and dpkg -l |grep "language-pack-fr" output?

Comment: @K-att- Thank you for your suggestion. It does not return anything. The dpkg -l returns 1916 lines but nothing containing "language-pack", and only one thing containing "pack-"

Comment: Does running the command `apt-get install -y locales locales-all` resolve the issue?

Comment: @ThatsWhatSheCoded Thank you for your suggestion. I edited the post with the result

Comment: Does this happen when you access that machine via SSH, or does it happen when you're working with a physical keyboard and monitor?

Comment: @Binarus It's happening physically on the PC. It's a laptop, an HP eq1110nf if that helps: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c07066419

Comment: When it's happening physically, I also have no idea. The idea with SSH would have been that SSH clients can send their own environment variables when connecting to the server, which might lead to problems of this type.

Comment: Can you try the following: uninstall the current locale package (`apt-get remove locale`) then reinstall the locale package (`apt-get install -y locale`), then open a new Terminal window and print what environment variables are set (`env`) and share that output in your post?

Comment: @ThatsWhatSheCoded Edited the post with this information. Thank you

Comment: Remove `export LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:fr` from your`.bashrc` then `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: @GAD3R It works, thank you! Please write the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `export LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:fr` from your`.bashrc` then run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.